# I don't understand why the source for my function code is not printing normally

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code and with I wanted to be able to have access to my functions directly without having to mess with the entire source code of the page.  The data originally came from the Apps Scripts API but know I've been extracting it from a file.

```
function readingAJSONFile() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.SOFJSONId);
  var jOb = JSON.parse(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  let files = jOb.files;
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    var cOb = files.reduce((a, f, i) => {
      //Logger.log(f.name);
      a.table.push([f.name, f.type, "", ""]);
      if (f.type == "SERVER_JS" && f.source != null) {
        a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source);//The is where I stringified the file source code
        //Logger.log('a.source: %s',a.source);
      }
      if (f.functionSet) {
        if (f.functionSet.values) {
          f.functionSet.values.forEach(obj => {
            let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\([^)]*\\)\\s*\\{.*?\\\\n\\}\\\\n`, "g");
            if (a.source.match(re)) {
              let src = a.source.match(re)[0];//once I began to stringy from above then this start functioning
              a.table.push(["", "", obj.name, src])
            }
          });
        }
      };
      return a;
    }, { source: "", table: [["FileName", "FileType", "Functions", "Source"]] });
  }
  if (cOb.table && cOb.table.length > 0) {
    return cOb.table;
  }
}

function startADialog(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1').evaluate().setWidth(1000).setHeight(500),"My Data");
}
```

With this file I open it with getDataAsString() and then use use JSON.parse on it.  That seems to work okay until I extracted the source code for the function out of the source code for the file with the regular expression and I use a RegExp so that I can insert the name into the regular expression to just get the functions from the file.  To be honest I have had a lot of trouble getting this to work reliably. In fact it doesn't work reliably yet.  I did manage to get the functions printed out but they no longer behave properly because all of their new line chars are displayed rather than rendered as shown below. And I guess I don't understand how to fix it.  It seems like it should be simple because it all came from the apps script api in the beginning which I presume is where they are storing our code.

[image]

The Data that I'm looking at is the exact same data that you get when you perform the following:

```
const scriptId = gobj.globals.scriptid;
  const url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content?fields=files(functionSet%2Cname%2Ctype)";
  const options = { "method": "get", "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  let data = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  let files = data.files.filter(f => f.type == "SERVER_JS");
```

After you parse it, it's a big object with all of your files including the SERVER_JS, HTML, and JSON.  It's where we see all of our code and it's return to us in one big JSON file.  I just saved that stringified object in a file because I'm been working on this a few days now I thought it would be easy to work with.

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your functions `readingAJSONFile` and `startADialog` and your showing image? For example, your function `readingAJSONFile` is called by the HTML template `ah1`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. If my understanding is correct, can you provide your HTML template `ah1`?

Comment: I tried to answer your question in my question at the bottom.  The dialog is just a place where I can view all of the script files and and of my code.  Its comes from the Apps Script API

Comment: The issue is that the new characters are embedded in the text rather than being rendered and I don't understand why.

Comment: From your reply, I could understand your question. In your script, `a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source);` is used in `readingAJSONFile()`. In this case, ``\`` is added for escaping. From your script, I guessed that you used it for using your regex. In this case, how about not using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: So, how about changing your current regex to ``let re = new RegExp(`function.*?${obj.name}.*?\\(.*\\).*\\{(.|\\n)*?\\n\\}`, "g");``. I modified this regex to your situation. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42987797). And, please modify `a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source)` to `a.source = f.source`, and test it again. When I tested this modification, it seems that the retrieved functions can be seen without `\n`. If my understanding was not correct and my proposal was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't think that the reqular expression would have that kind of effect upon what it captures.  That's going to take me some time to figure that one out.  Thank you so much for your help.  I started out not using the JSON.stringify but at that point I was not getting for the source at all.  I guess I should have investigated what I was getting a  little closere.  Thanys for the help.  I will try to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue. But, if your issue was not resolved, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Cooper Consider adding it as a answer instead of edits to the question. It's hard for someone to see that the question is answered, just by the edits.

Comment: @Tanaike Would you placing your comment in the answer so I can select it as the answer and give what little credit that I can.  I finally realized this morning that it was changing of `f.source` to a `stringified` version that led to my downfall.  That's where the text embedded `\n` came from.  What I needed to do was to remove the stringify and return to solving the problem with a proper regex solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I understand your reply. I posted it as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source)` is used in the function `readingAJSONFile()`. In this case, `\` is added for escaping. From your script, I guessed that you used it for using your regex. In this case, how about not using `JSON.stringify` and using the raw value of `f.source`?

When your script is modified, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source);
```

#### To:

```
a.source = f.source; // Here, the raw string value is used.
```

Also, please modify the regex as follows.

#### From:

```
let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\([^)]*\\)\\s*\\{.*?\\\\n\\}\\\\n`, "g");
```

#### To:

```
let re = new RegExp(`function.*?${obj.name}.*?\\(.*\\).*\\{(.|\\n)*?\\n\\}`, "g");
```

- I modified the regex from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42987797) for your situation.
- By this modification, it seems that the retrieved functions can be seen without `\n`.

Comment: I decided to use this instead because your use of .* was missing some functions and picking other choices more than once. `let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\([^)]*\\)[ \r\n]*\\{(.|\\n)*?\\n\\}`, "g");` and I have come to write my functions in a fairly precise way most of the time.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your additional information.